# How to add a column that contains the corresponding column name with the largest number in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, data-science

I have a data frame like this:

```
A1 A2 A3 ...A99 largest
0   3  4  6      11   11
1   1  8  2  ...  1    8
.
.
.
```

I created the column which contains the largest value in each row by using:

```
data['largest']=data.max(axis=1)
```

but I also want to get a column which contains the corresponding column name with the largest number, something like this:

```
    A1 A2 A3 ...A99 largest name
0   3  4  6      11   11    A99
1   1  8  2  ...  1    8    A2
.                            .
.                            .
.                            .
```

I tried '.idxmax' but gave me an error'reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype', can someone help me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for add 2 columns without inference each other:

```
df = data.assign(largest=data.max(axis=1), name=data.idxmax(axis=1))
print (df)
   A1  A2  A3  A99  largest name
0   3   4   6   11       11  A99
1   1   8   2    1        8   A2
```

Or [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html):

```
data[['largest','name']] = data.agg(['max','idxmax'], 1)
print (data)
   A1  A2  A3  A99 largest name
0   3   4   6   11      11  A99
1   1   8   2    1       8   A2
```

EDIT:

You can select only numeric columns:

```
df1 = data.select_dtypes(np.number)
```

Or convert columns to numeric:

```
df1 = data.astype(int)
```

If not working `.astype` because possible some non numeric value use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert problematic values no `NaN`:

```
df1 = data.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
```

---

```
df = data.assign(largest=df1.max(axis=1), name=df1.idxmax(axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually tried '.idxmax' but gave me an error'reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype', I have no idea why this showed up because I checked the datatype, it's dataframe type

Comment: @Cecilia - it seems some columns are non numeric, give me a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) to keep the column name where a value is equal to `largest`:

```
df['name'] = df.iloc[:,:-1].eq(df.largest.values[:,None]).dot(df.columns[:-1])

   A1  A2  A3  A99  largest name
0   3   4   6   11       11  A99
1   1   8   2    1        8   A2
```

Comment: I got an error 'shapes (100,)' and (50,), not aligned: 100(dim 0)!=50(dim 0)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`np.argmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
df=df.assign(name=df.columns[np.argmax(df.values,axis=1)])
```

---

```
   A1  A2  A3  A99  largest name
0   3   4   6   11       11  A99
1   1   8   2    1        8   A2
```